# service is not running properly in android 10

Tags: services, android-10

I have created script and i.e running via service in ini.rc.

init: starting service 'usbmountd '...

[ 1350.212500] init: Service 'usbmountd ' (pid 6923) received signal 11

[ 1350.212626] init: Sending signal 9 to service 'usbmountd ' (pid 6923) process group...

[ 1350.213261] libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 0 pid 6923 in 0ms

[ 1350.213917] init: updatable process 'usbmountd ' exited 4 times in 4 minutes

[ 1350.221191] init: Init cannot set 'ro.init.updatable_crashing' to '1': Read-only property was already set

getting this log in dmesg.

Comment: This feels like a programming question which is off-topic. You should [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/223779/edit) your question with what are you trying to do and if the device is rooted.

Comment: initially i just want to check my script is running or not.

Comment: What's wrong with echo-ing out datetime with state/messages to a temp file? Still leaning toward off-topic as I don't see how specifically Android end-user related. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39135/stack-overflow-for-hardware-embedded-systems